# Does time travel affect Perfect Town rating on Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

As far as I'm concerned, my town is pretty perfect. I have everything needed but whenever I talk to Isabelle, she tells me that the citizens say that it's "riding the so-so rails" and it's so annoying because I see no faults and the only flaw she points out is "all the weeds and garbage".

I have scoped my town a hundred times for weeds and garbage and there is definitely none, but it never changes.

However, the other day it changed to something like "goodness gracious if it goes on like this, this town'll be great" or whatever. I was like "wow!" finally some recognition for all my hard work. Then, I time-traveled a little bit, (only a couple hours), then the next day it went back to "riding the so-so rails". There are no weeds or garbage!

Answer (score 1):

Yes time travel can affect your perfect town status, but time travelling itself isn't exactly the problem.

Basically, just follow [this guide](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/perfect-town-guide).

To summarize, aside from weeds and garbage, some PWPs can also affect your town negatively. The drilling rig and the television screen don't help you, and garbage cans don't help either for some reason. Leaving items on the ground, like clothing and bells, count as garbage until you pick them up. Having more, if not the maximum, amount of villagers will also make your villagers happy

Comment: Please summarize the relevant information from the link.  That way, if the site ever goes down, your answer will be more useful.  Just linking somewhere and telling readers to follow that is frowned upon, as that risks the page disappearing and your answer becoming stale.